# Open PIL image from byte file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkvLY.png) with size 128 x 128 pixels and RGBA stored as byte values in my memory. But

```
from PIL import Image

image_data = ... # byte values of the image
image = Image.frombytes('RGBA', (128,128), image_data)
image.show()
```

throws the exception

> ValueError: not enough image data

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the raw data in a `.png` file has headers and compression and stuff, so I don't think you can feed it into `frombytes` and get a coherent result.

Comment: How do I get rid of this?

Comment: I guess you could open the image with `Image.open("homer.jpg")`, and then call `tobytes` on it to get a buffer suitable for passing to `frombytes`... But there's not much point in doing `image = Image.frombytes(Image.open("homer.jpg").tobytes())` when you can just do `image = Image.open("homer.jpg")`. I'm assuming your actual use case is more complicated and you can't do the latter for some reason.

Comment: But I do not want to start at a stored file, but a in-memory bytes-array (coming directly from a socket).

Comment: So your actual question is "how do I read data from a socket?"?

Comment: No, this works already. But instead of _socket -> store image to file -> load from this file -> done_ I want _socket -> done_ . I tried to make the question a little bit more clear!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can try this:

```
image = Image.frombytes('RGBA', (128,128), image_data, 'raw')
```

> Source Code:
>
> ```
> def frombytes(mode, size, data, decoder_name="raw", *args):
>     param mode: The image mode.
>     param size: The image size.
>     param data: A byte buffer containing raw data for the given mode.
>     param decoder_name: What decoder to use.
> ```

Comment: The [Image.frombuffer()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombuffer) function can be also useful, as it doesn't create a new buffer, but instead uses (if possible) the original buffer.

Comment: This answer is unusable due to Image.frombytes lacks good description. I just want to pass jpg image through curl and get problems due to frombytes say completly nothing about what to do with compressed images

Comment: > Note that this function decodes pixel data only, not entire images. If you have an entire image in a string, wrap it in a BytesIO object, and use open() to load it.

Answer (score 382):

[The documentation for `Image.open`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) says that it can accept a file-like object, so you should be able to pass in a `io.BytesIO` object created from the `bytes` object containing the encoded image:

```
from PIL import Image
import io

image_data = ... # byte values of the image
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
image.show()
```

Comment: Doesn't `Image.open` or `io.BytesIO` needs to know what image format it is being given somehow?

Comment: @JeromeJ Most image formats have a header that identifies the format in use. Pillow uses that to identify the image. See [the PNG header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header) for an example.

Comment: This answer is right, just as suggested in the documentation. But, it is still not clear to me what they mean in the documentation by "Note that this function decodes pixel data only, not entire images." when referring to the .fromBytes() method. Any ideas?

Comment: @BluePython `fromBytes` is for raw arrays of pixels, such as a `width*height` long array of `RGBA` values. `open` is for images encoded in a specific format, such as PNG or JPEG, that usually compress the pixel data and may have other data that needs dealing with, such as headers or EXIF info.

Comment: It loses the mode RGB and just has one channel

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer,..just confirming, the io.BytesIO(image_data)) will create a buffer of image_data in the ram and will return a file-like object. Have I understood it correctly?