# Cannot open mysterious DICOM file using Python

Tags: python, image, dicom

I am trying to open a [DICOM](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ulvn5yz4umoq6n2/1_Video.dcm?dl=0) file which is accompanied by a [.jpeg file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4zdy6bup98brxy4/1_DThumbN.jpg?dl=0). This pair of files is the result of exporting the image acquisition from an imaging device which I guess is a proprietary DICOM or something. Still I can read the information and tags of the file except viewing the actual image data.

I am using PyDicom and do the following:

```
import pydicom
myfile = pydicom.read_file("thedicomfile.dcm")
myfile.pixel_array # results in error
AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'TransferSyntaxUID'
# so I do 
myfile.file_meta.TransferSyntaxUID = pydicom.uid.ImplicitVRLittleEndian
# then 
myfile.pixel_array
```

> lAttributeError: Amount of pixel data 19404 does not match the expected data 76800

I don't know that to do or how to exploit the information from the .jpg file which accompanies my DICOM.

(The data are of myself and also randomly changed time of birth, so no problem with confidentiality)

```
Hex dump of file 1:
file name: 1_DThumbN.jpg
mime type: 

0000-0010:  49 49 2a 00-08 00 00 00-18 00 fe 00-04 00 01 00  II*..... ........
0000-0020:  00 00 00 00-00 00 00 01-04 00 01 00-00 00 80 00  ........ ........
0000-0030:  00 00 01 01-04 00 01 00-00 00 80 00-00 00 02 01  ........ ........
0000-0040:  03 00 03 00-00 00 2e 01-00 00 03 01-03 00 01 00  ........ ........
0000-0050:  00 00 07 00-00 00 06 01-03 00 01 00-00 00 06 00  ........ ........
0000-0060:  00 00 12 01-03 00 01 00-00 00 01 00-00 00 15 01  ........ ........
0000-0070:  03 00 01 00-00 00 03 00-00 00 1a 01-05 00 01 00  ........ ........
0000-0080:  00 00 64 01-00 00 1b 01-05 00 01 00-00 00 6c 01  ..d..... ......l.
0000-0090:  00 00 1c 01-03 00 01 00-00 00 01 00-00 00 28 01  ........ ......(.
0000-00a0:  03 00 01 00-00 00 02 00-00 00 29 01-03 00 02 00  ........ ..).....
0000-00b0:  00 00 00 00-00 00 42 01-03 00 01 00-00 00 80 00  ......B. ........
0000-00c0:  00 00 43 01-03 00 01 00-00 00 80 00-00 00 44 01  ..C..... ......D.
0000-00d0:  04 00 01 00-00 00 f4 03-00 00 45 01-04 00 01 00  ........ ..E.....
0000-00e0:  00 00 e2 08-00 00 00 02-03 00 01 00-00 00 01 00  ........ ........
0000-00f0:  00 00 01 02-04 00 01 00-00 00 74 01-00 00 02 02  ........ ..t.....
0000-0100:  04 00 01 00-00 00 62 0b-00 00 03 02-03 00 01 00  ......b. ........
0000-0110:  00 00 00 00-00 00 12 02-03 00 02 00-00 00 02 00  ........ ........
0000-0120:  01 00 13 02-03 00 01 00-00 00 02 00-00 00 14 02  ........ ........
0000-0130:  05 00 06 00-00 00 34 01-00 00 00 00-00 00 08 00  ......4. ........
0000-0140:  08 00 08 00-00 00 00 00-01 00 00 00-ff 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0150:  01 00 00 00-80 00 00 00-01 00 00 00-ff 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0160:  01 00 00 00-80 00 00 00-01 00 00 00-ff 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0170:  01 00 00 00-96 00 00 00-01 00 00 00-96 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0180:  01 00 00 00-ff d8 ff e0-00 10 4a 46-49 46 00 01  ........ ..JFIF..
0000-0190:  00 01 00 96-00 96 00 00-ff fe 00 1f-4c 45 41 44  ........ ....LEAD
0000-01a0:  20 54 65 63-68 6e 6f 6c-6f 67 69 65-73 20 49 6e  .Technol ogies.In
0000-01b0:  63 2e 20 56-31 2e 30 31-00 ff db 00-84 00 20 16  c..V1.01 ........
0000-01c0:  18 1c 18 14-20 1c 1a 1c-24 22 20 26-30 50 34 30  ........ $".&0P40
0000-01d0:  2c 2c 30 62-46 4a 3a 50-74 66 7a 78-72 66 70 6e  ,,0bFJ:P tfzxrfpn
0000-01e0:  80 90 b8 9c-80 88 ae 8a-6e 70 a0 da-a2 ae be c4  ........ np......
0000-01f0:  ce d0 ce 7c-9a e2 f2 e0-c8 f0 b8 ca-ce c6 01 22  ...|.... ......."
0000-0200:  24 24 30 2a-30 5e 34 34-5e c6 84 70-84 c6 c6 c6  $$0*0^44 ^..p....
0000-0210:  c6 c6 c6 c6-c6 c6 c6 c6-c6 c6 c6 c6-c6 c6 c6 c6  ........ ........
0000-0220:  c6 c6 c6 c6-c6 c6 c6 c6-c6 c6 c6 c6-c6 c6 c6 c6  ........ ........
0000-0230:  c6 c6 c6 c6-c6 c6 c6 c6-c6 c6 c6 c6-c6 c6 c6 ff  ........ ........
0000-0240:  c4 01 a2 00-00 01 05 01-01 01 01 01-01 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0250:  00 00 00 00-00 01 02 03-04 05 06 07-08 09 0a 0b  ........ ........
0000-0260:  01 00 03 01-01 01 01 01-01 01 01 01-00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0270:  00 00 01 02-03 04 05 06-07 08 09 0a-0b 10 00 02  ........ ........
0000-0280:  01 03 03 02-04 03 05 05-04 04 00 00-01 7d 01 02  ........ .....}..
0000-0290:  03 00 04 11-05 12 21 31-41 06 13 51-61 07 22 71  ......!1 A..Qa."q
0000-02a0:  14 32 81 91-a1 08 23 42-b1 c1 15 52-d1 f0 24 33  .2....#B ...R..$3
0000-02b0:  62 72 82 09-0a 16 17 18-19 1a 25 26-27 28 29 2a  br...... ..%&'()*
0000-02c0:  34 35 36 37-38 39 3a 43-44 45 46 47-48 49 4a 53  456789:C DEFGHIJS
0000-02d0:  54 55 56 57-58 59 5a 63-64 65 66 67-68 69 6a 73  TUVWXYZc defghijs
0000-02e0:  74 75 76 77-78 79 7a 83-84 85 86 87-88 89 8a 92  tuvwxyz. ........
0000-02f0:  93 94 95 96-97 98 99 9a-a2 a3 a4 a5-a6 a7 a8 a9  ........ ........
0000-0300:  aa b2 b3 b4-b5 b6 b7 b8-b9 ba c2 c3-c4 c5 c6 c7  ........ ........
0000-0310:  c8 c9 ca d2-d3 d4 d5 d6-d7 d8 d9 da-e1 e2 e3 e4  ........ ........
0000-0320:  e5 e6 e7 e8-e9 ea f1 f2-f3 f4 f5 f6-f7 f8 f9 fa  ........ ........
0000-0330:  11 00 02 01-02 04 04 03-04 07 05 04-04 00 01 02  ........ ........
0000-0340:  77 00 01 02-03 11 04 05-21 31 06 12-41 51 07 61  w....... !1..AQ.a
0000-0350:  71 13 22 32-81 08 14 42-91 a1 b1 c1-09 23 33 52  q."2...B .....#3R
0000-0360:  f0 15 62 72-d1 0a 16 24-34 e1 25 f1-17 18 19 1a  ..br...$ 4.%.....
0000-0370:  26 27 28 29-2a 35 36 37-38 39 3a 43-44 45 46 47  &'()*567 89:CDEFG
0000-0380:  48 49 4a 53-54 55 56 57-58 59 5a 63-64 65 66 67  HIJSTUVW XYZcdefg
0000-0390:  68 69 6a 73-74 75 76 77-78 79 7a 82-83 84 85 86  hijstuvw xyz.....
0000-03a0:  87 88 89 8a-92 93 94 95-96 97 98 99-9a a2 a3 a4  ........ ........
0000-03b0:  a5 a6 a7 a8-a9 aa b2 b3-b4 b5 b6 b7-b8 b9 ba c2  ........ ........
0000-03c0:  c3 c4 c5 c6-c7 c8 c9 ca-d2 d3 d4 d5-d6 d7 d8 d9  ........ ........
0000-03d0:  da e2 e3 e4-e5 e6 e7 e8-e9 ea f2 f3-f4 f5 f6 f7  ........ ........
0000-03e0:  f8 f9 fa ff-c0 00 11 08-00 80 00 80-03 01 21 00  ........ ......!.
0000-03f0:  02 11 01 03-11 01 ff da-00 0c 03 01-00 02 11 03  ........ ........
0000-0400:  11 00 3f 00-e7 e8 1c 50-01 45 00 14-50 01 45 00  ..?....P .E..P.E.
0000-0410:  1d 68 a0 02-8a 00 28 a0-02 8a 00 3b-51 40 05 1d  .h....(. ...;Q@..
0000-0420:  a8 00 a2 80-0a 28 01 f1-c3 2c 9c 47-1b b6 7f ba  .....(.. .,.G....
0000-0430:  09 a9 92 c6-e1 b3 fb 96-18 c9 39 18-c5 27 38 ad  ........ ..9..'8.
0000-0440:  24 c4 d8 d9-2d a5 0d 85-86 4e 83 82-a7 35 0f 6f  $...-... .N...5.o
0000-0450:  7a a7 6b e8-24 ee 21 e3-ad 14 14 14-10 46 32 3a  z.k.$.!. .....F2:
0000-0460:  f4 a4 01 df-02 8a 00 28-a0 03 3c 62-9f 14 4f 33  .......( ..<b..O3
0000-0470:  6c 8c 64 e3-3f 4a 04 dd-95 cd 25 d3-e0 89 17 cc  l.d.?J.. ..%.....
0000-0480:  73 bf 77 de-ec 79 e0 73-f4 e6 a6 8a-28 21 0a 44  s.w..y.s ....(!.D
0000-0490:  78 96 33 bb-0d f3 60 0c-1e bc 7a 8f-cf eb 59 37  x.3...`. ..z...Y7
0000-04a0:  29 46 c8 e7-f6 8d b2 48-8c 6e b1 c4-d9 60 23 d9  )F.....H .n...`#.
0000-04b0:  d1 5b 93 fc-43 d3 a1 3d-7d 3b d4 81-d3 2c 5e 50  .[..C..= };...,^P
0000-04c0:  cb b7 3f 33-6d 3d 7d fa-73 b8 7e 9d-ab 29 a6 ee  ..?3m=}. s.~..)..
0000-04d0:  9a f3 fb ff-00 12 a3 36-9a 69 6c 49-e6 c2 5f 07  .......6 .ilI.._.
0000-04e0:  6e d0 79 c3-f2 08 e3 18-fc 87 d7 1f-5a 64 96 d0  n.y..... ....Zd..
0000-04f0:  ce 59 a4 89-58 ee db 9c-73 d3 bf 3c-9e 7f cf 15  .Y..X... s..<....
0000-0500:  8a e6 87 53-6b f3 d8 48-e0 b5 52 4c-71 07 23 e5  ...Sk..H ..RLq.#.
0000-0510:  25 47 4e d8-ff 00 3e 95-56 e3 4c 49-b6 bc 4c b1  %GN...>. V.LI..L.
0000-0520:  02 bd c6 01-3d 7a 76 ad-55 59 c2 5e-f8 d2 8b 4b  ....=zv. UY.^...K
0000-0530:  97 73 22 48-da 27 28 e3-6b 0e a2 9b-5d 60 29 e3  .s"H.'(. k...]`).
0000-0540:  a8 c5 04 f1-8e d4 00 f8-a2 79 9b 64-6b b9 8f a5  ........ .y.dk...
0000-0550:  5d 8f 4d 45-5c dc 5c 46-a7 b2 06 00-9f c4 f4 3c  ].ME\.\F .......<
0000-0560:  8a 89 ce da-2d c9 72 49-d8 95 34 98-64 2a 44 ae  ....-.rI ..4.d*D.
0000-0570:  17 68 24 91-d4 e3 9f a7-51 d6 ae 06-8e dd 5a 2b  .h$..... Q.....Z+
0000-0580:  78 c8 66 f9-94 63 19 c6-3a 93 9c 7a-74 ac 65 27  x.f..c.. :..zt.e'
0000-0590:  36 a3 f7 ff-00 5b ff 00-5e 86 73 77-5a e8 51 9e  6....[.. ^.swZ.Q.
0000-05a0:  e0 16 2f b7-0a 4e 09 0c-18 7b f7 19-c8 0b d7 de  ../..N.. .{......
0000-05b0:  98 8b 3d c2-e1 e3 51 18-3b 89 31 f3-c9 ec 6b a2  ..=...Q. ;.1...k.
0000-05c0:  2b 91 5e 5f-d7 f5 f7 12-91 33 e9 8c-59 8b 4a 4b  +.^_.... .3..Y.JK
0000-05d0:  05 38 dd 81-c9 fa 9f 5c-fb d4 83 4e-55 6d a2 56  .8.....\ ...NUm.V
0000-05e0:  62 1b 38 c8-c6 46 4f 7e-dd 79 ac d6-20 df d9 49  b.8..FO~ .y.....I
0000-05f0:  e9 b7 f5 ea-36 68 24 4b-79 48 9b 28-41 3b 41 c7  ....6h$K yH.(A;A.
0000-0600:  3b 71 cf b6-07 f8 d4 26-e6 48 46 6e-37 19 a3 ce  ;q.....& .HFn7...
0000-0610:  04 a9 91 8e-9c 1e e7 8e-b9 a7 17 0a-ab 6b 3f ea  ........ .....k?.
0000-0620:  e4 3a 52 81-3c 7a 86 ec-34 a5 fe 51-b8 2e d1 d7  .:R.<z.. 4..Q....
0000-0630:  1f 36 33 d4-63 07 ae 79-ab be 7a 4b-12 b4 9b b0  .63.c..y ..zK....
0000-0640:  e3 20 28 ed-8e 7a 74 06-b9 ea 51 e5-7a 6e 25 51  ..(..zt. ..Q.zn%Q
0000-0650:  ad c8 1d 61-b8 3e 53 22-12 17 1b 8a-9e 31 db 9e  ...a.>S" .....1..
0000-0660:  98 ee 3f fa-f5 56 6d 25-19 09 89 f6-b2 f0 54 9c  ..?..Vm% ......T.
0000-0670:  8f 5f cb 15-51 9c a9 e9-24 69 cd 19-3f 74 48 3e  ._..Q... $i..?tH>
0000-0680:  cd 2c 9b 25-82 25 76 3b-48 1c 05 3b-78 ef f5 ff  .,.%.%v; H..;x...
0000-0690:  00 f5 d4 ab-61 66 ec 5d-43 15 eb b7-76 07 a6 32  ....af.] C...v..2
0000-06a0:  47 f5 ad 65-cf 1d 17 f5-fe 66 5c fa-d8 bb 18 48  G..e.... .f\....H
0000-06b0:  62 5f e0 8f-39 2a 40 db-c7 7f eb ff-00 d7 a6 04  b_..9*@. ........
0000-06c0:  dc 17 ce 53-b9 4e 5b b8-63 c9 00 f3-c7 5c fa 57  ...S.N[. c....\.W
0000-06d0:  3a 6f 9b 99-7f 5f d6 82-8b 4d 5a ff-00 d7 f5 fd  :o..._.. .MZ.....
0000-06e0:  6a 51 bb bc-56 26 28 b0-ab 9f be 18-82 a7 d3 fc  jQ..V&(. ........
0000-06f0:  f1 cf 6a ab-11 99 d1 52-23 b5 07 1b-88 23 9e 78  ..j....R #....#.x
0000-0700:  fa 8c 9e 95-db 18 f2 a4-9e e1 15 a6-a5 c8 34 f8  ........ ......4.
0000-0710:  a0 52 f7 12-02 d8 ce 19-3e e8 c1 cf-d4 fe 7d 3d  .R...... >.....}=
0000-0720:  ea c0 b9 40-ec ca cb b2-21 8f 98 70-a7 b0 fc fd  ...@.... !..p....
0000-0730:  b1 c7 b5 73-49 7b 47 7e-9d 0b f6 9c-ad a4 23 5d  ...sI{G~ ......#]
0000-0740:  9f 21 b1 b7-76 c4 6c a0-c0 c9 3d 79-f4 e3 fc f4  .!..v.l. ..=y....
0000-0750:  6b 4a c6 73-19 da aa 64-da a5 40 3b-5b 23 2d ed  kJ.s...d ..@;[#-.
0000-0760:  cf f3 e6 85-4e 31 df fa-d8 85 39 37-a1 28 df 89  ....N1.. ..97.(..
0000-0770:  0c 81 9a 22-bf 78 e3 9e-32 78 3d 3f-1c fd 68 8b  ...".x.. 2x=?..h.
0000-0780:  65 ca 82 f1-8d c0 6e 65-91 3a 67 bf-fe 3b fe 73  e.....ne .:g..;.s
0000-0790:  59 b4 92 e6-83 34 85 47-b4 b6 22 6d-32 19 1b 28  Y....4.G .."m2..(
0000-07a0:  c2 37 6e d8-dc 07 39 ef-54 e2 b6 ba-da 02 8c f9  .7n...9. T.......
0000-07b0:  25 8a fc db-7a e3 3d 7e-a3 fc 9a de-15 74 fd e2  %...z.=~ .....t..
0000-07c0:  d8 5a 49 da-2e e1 2c b7-11 c8 db d4-30 1f 3f 39  .ZI...,. ....0.?9
0000-07d0:  2a 0f a8 cf-4e 84 71 fe-14 86 65 65-79 02 c4 01  *...N.q. ..eey...
0000-07e0:  66 23 79 24-f4 ce 00 ed-cf f3 fc f7-e5 57 f7 4c  f#y$.... .....W.L
0000-07f0:  dc 2c 33 ca-ba db 86 82-46 1f 7b 23-3f 9f d7 83  .,3..... F.{#?...
0000-0800:  d7 9a 21 92-58 b6 29 06-21 86 01 8e-4f 7c 9e 9f  ..!.X.). !...O|..
0000-0810:  4c 1a 5c ca-5a 5c a6 95-84 49 b9 7d-d3 3b 2f 23  L.\.Z\.. .I.}.;/#
0000-0820:  0c 33 c1 1f-5e b8 fc 2a-78 5e f2 65-01 11 c0 93  .3..^..* x^.e....
0000-0830:  ef 9c 60 37-5e 40 e9 eb-f9 d2 9d b7-90 9a 4b c8  ..`7^@.. ......K.
0000-0840:  b9 6d 65 0d-bc ab 2b 3b-33 12 72 5c-7a f4 eb d3  .me...+; 3.r\z...
0000-0850:  f5 fa 8a 59-2e 4c 68 fb-15 09 05 49-f9 87 cd 8e  ...Y.Lh. ...I....
0000-0860:  dc f3 db f4-3f 5a e5 d6-b4 bc be ff-00 eb fa b9  ....?Z.. ........
0000-0870:  a4 9c 63 b6-ff 00 d7 f5-d8 8e 29 da-23 23 c9 26  ..c..... ..).##.&
0000-0880:  e6 66 00 05-c6 50 13 d3-9e 83 a5 40-b3 2f 9e de  .f...P.. ...@./..
0000-0890:  5b 23 2b 9d-a6 30 bc 1e-be fd 39 f7-eb d2 ba 55  [#+..0.. ..9....U
0000-08a0:  1d 5d ba fe-9f f0 7f 33-0b b6 b6 d0-87 ed 7b 13  .].....3 ......{.
0000-08b0:  38 dc 1a 32-a0 02 40 f4-c6 3b 70 3b-75 e2 a5 37  8..2..@. .;p;u..7
0000-08c0:  c7 23 00 b1-20 13 f3 95-c6 40 f5 eb-f5 1f e3 56  .#...... .@.....V
0000-08d0:  a1 d8 72 83-7d 49 4d d0-99 9b 0d bc-67 2f c6 11  ..r.}IM. ....g/..
0000-08e0:  8e 3d fa 63-68 f5 3d 7d-29 d1 4f 6a-c4 ec 47 dc  .=.ch.=} ).Oj..G.
0000-08f0:  e3 12 1c 6d-3d 79 24 8e-07 ff 00 5f-d2 b2 e4 69  ...m=y$. ..._...i
0000-0900:  5a 3d 04 f9-88 d8 32 c9-90 cc db db-e4 76 7f e2  Z=....2. .....v..
0000-0910:  0d d0 f1 d3-d8 7f f5 c3-6d ee d2 08-84 77 03 7e  ........ m....w.~
0000-0920:  00 d8 73 91-f4 27 fc 33-44 a1 cf 1b-44 ba 72 69  ..s..'.3 D...D.ri
0000-0930:  e9 a3 34 76-99 11 96 37-ce e6 e4 16-07 18 fd 73  ..4v...7 .......s
0000-0940:  51 bd ba 4a-99 64 59 06-40 e3 3d 3d-ff 00 3f e7  Q..J.dY. @.==..?.
0000-0950:  5c b7 94 1e-8f fa f9 ff-00 c3 1d 0a-ac 6a 47 58  \....... .....jGX
0000-0960:  ff 00 5f d7-f5 b8 0b a0-1d 10 fc d2-3f 54 19 ed  .._..... ....?T..
0000-0970:  db 19 eb f5-e9 83 cd 2b-4b 03 10 30-8c 54 16 1b  .......+ K..0.T..
0000-0980:  fd 07 04 91-8e 3b ff 00-f5 e9 fb 39-45 de 3f d7  .....;.. ...9E.?.
0000-0990:  99 0e af 35-94 95 bf af-90 b2 49 6c-1d 58 a8 0c  ...5.... ..Il.X..
0000-09a0:  41 55 23 f8-86 7f 5e b9-fc 7d aa 09-ae 51 22 54  AU#...^. .}...Q"T
0000-09b0:  42 44 67 80-03 6e 24 76-18 3d 47 5e-9e 95 ad 3a  BDg..n$v .=G^...:
0000-09c0:  52 95 9c df-f4 8c e5 52-cf 96 0b 41-ab 70 f7 0d  R......R ...A.p..
0000-09d0:  bd 91 c8 24-e0 23 29 db-8c 60 93 dc-e4 9e b9 a6  ...$.#). .`......
0000-09e0:  32 ac 71 2a-5b b1 28 cd-90 19 80 c7-7c 7a 8c e4  2.q*[.(. ....|z..
0000-09f0:  7e 7e 9d 75-84 39 5a 4b-fa b7 f5 ff-00 07 63 37  ~~.u.9ZK ......c7
0000-0a00:  24 f7 29 48-f2 7d a1 8a-b7 cc 46 ec-2a f0 72 b5  $.)H.}.. ..F.*.r.
0000-0a10:  5d dc bb 96-65 1b 89 24-9f 5a d7 cc-da 29 74 11  ]...e..$ .Z...)t.
0000-0a20:  98 b6 7d 33-9c 50 08 5f-70 45 0a c5-d8 70 93 68  ..}3.P._ pE...p.h
0000-0a30:  52 83 69 19-ef 9c f1 e9-52 45 3e d9-10 0e 53 20  R.i..... RE>...S.
0000-0a40:  6c 6e 9e fc-f6 e4 51 72-1c 6e 4e 97-19 d8 ac aa  ln....Qr .nN.....
0000-0a50:  a0 8c b6 10-8d 83 24 f1-8f 63 50 a8-df 06 77 2a  ......$. .cP...w*
0000-0a60:  95 60 41 ce-48 1d 3d c8-19 c7 e7 46-89 10 a3 62  .`A.H.=. ...F...b
0000-0a70:  c4 c0 86 f3-01 da c9 80-03 27 2f b7-a1 cf 7e 3b  ........ .'/...~;
0000-0a80:  fd 3f 07 43-7a f1 21 79-17 3c e5 48-18 07 a8 24  .?.Cz.!y .<.H...$
0000-0a90:  77 19 3e 9e-86 a5 c5 3f-74 94 ae ae-44 5e 6f 28  w.>....? t...D^o(
0000-0aa0:  14 f3 19 8e-40 6d d9 cf-d3 07 ae 0f-bf 4f ad 3a  ....@m.. .....O.:
0000-0ab0:  29 4f 94 63-6c 86 38 4d-b9 38 c1 00-67 8c 7a 0e  )O.cl.8M .8..g.z.
0000-0ac0:  e7 bd 39 2b-b1 e9 6d 09-9e e1 a4 91-52 3d 8e a5  ..9+..m. ....R=..
0000-0ad0:  01 1b d0 1c-12 40 ea 3a-67 8c fb fa-55 61 32 3e  .....@.: g...Ua2>
0000-0ae0:  cd e3 0a 23-2a 14 9e 32-09 c7 7e 98-34 a3 14 96  ...#*..2 ..~.4...
0000-0af0:  80 93 b0 ef-b4 22 c8 cd-8f ba b8 f9-4e 01 f9 b3  .....".. ....N...
0000-0b00:  c6 08 3d 4f-4f 6f ca bb-cb b8 bb 05-1f 37 50 4e  ..=OOo.. .....7PN
0000-0b10:  41 3e bc f3-9c e4 d3 4a-da 95 18 b2-20 c4 77 e9  A>.....J ......w.
0000-0b20:  49 d4 f4 fc-a9 dc d4 3d-69 29 0c 33-4a 31 df 91  I......= i).3J1..
0000-0b30:  40 0a 0e 71-9c 9c 0e 94-0f ba 7a 63-df b5 35 a8  @..q.... ..zc..5.
0000-0b40:  89 52 7d ac-72 58 a9 18-c7 1d 33 ef-9a 5f 31 76  .R}.rX.. ..3.._1v
0000-0b50:  61 06 d1 d0-b1 51 cf 71-cf a9 3f e4-d3 ba 33 70  a....Q.q ..?...3p
0000-0b60:  b0 d3 29 21-48 04 6d c7-38 e8 71 ed-f4 fd 2a 64  ..)!H.m. 8.q...*d
0000-0b70:  76 70 53 76-c7 71 b4 12-33 bc 12 7f-2f 4e 29 ee  vpSv.q.. 3.../N).
0000-0b80:  12 8a 48 64-ae 49 f9 db-23 00 29 c0-e5 46 79 ff  ..Hd.I.. #.)..Fy.
0000-0b90:  00 eb 53 32-37 12 47 cb-9e 09 c1 e7-8c e3 b1 a2  ..S27.G. ........
0000-0ba0:  ed 2b 30 4b-b0 34 87 cc-04 7c a7 a3-64 7e 7c 7e  .+0K.4.. .|..d~|~
0000-0bb0:  95 16 48 6c-f4 22 a6 4c-b8 a1 28 a9-28 51 8a 4f  ..Hl.".L ..(.(Q.O
0000-0bc0:  5a 60 14 bd-f9 fd 68 40-1e d4 aa c5-73 dc 11 82  Z`....h@ ....s...
0000-0bd0:  33 40 85 62-0e 30 a3 3d-f1 4d c1 e9-9f 7e b4 d8  3@.b.0.= .M...~..
0000-0be0:  20 c7 19 1f-fe aa 77 f0-7d 3a f3 d4-71 40 07 98  ......w. }:..q@..
0000-0bf0:  4f df 25 f9-cf 27 8a 6f-eb 49 bb 82-56 03 d4 8e  O.%..'.o .I..V...
0000-0c00:  3d 29 28 18-b8 ff 00 3e-b4 94 80 5c-7b 8a 4a 60  =)(....> ...\{.J`
0000-0c10:  14 76 a4 01-45 30 17 8c-7b d2 b1 04-e7 9e 7a e4  .v..E0.. {.....z.
0000-0c20:  e6 81 0d ef-4b 9e 28 18-0e 0f 34 94-00 b8 e3 34  ....K.(. ..4....4
0000-0c30:  94 00 0e 28-a0 02 8a 40-14 50 02 8a-4a 00 3f 1a  ...(...@ .P..J.?.
0000-0c40:  5e dd 29 80-94 b4 80 07-1c d2 53 00-fa d1 40 0a  ^.)..... ..S...@.
0000-0c50:  7d a9 29 00-51 40 05 14-00 52 8a 60-25 29 c0 c7  }.).Q@.. .R.`%)..
0000-0c60:  1f 5a 40 25-2e 78 c5 00-19 ce 79 a4-a0 05 cf 5e  .Z@%.x.. ..y....^
0000-0c70:  07 3f a5 25-00 1d 7a 51-40 05 14 00-a4 92 72 4e  .?.%..zQ @.....rN
0000-0c80:  4d 25 00 14-1a 00 28 ed-40 05 29 39-3e b4 c0 01  M%....(. @.)9>...
0000-0c90:  20 10 0f 5e-0d 04 e4 01-e8 3d 29 00-94 50 01 fc  ...^.... .=)..P..
0000-0ca0:  a8 a0 02 8a-00 29 73 f4-e2 80 12 8a-00 28 a0 02  .....)s. .....(..
0000-0cb0:  8a 00 28 a0-02 8a 00 28-a0 03 ad 14-00 51 40 05  ..(....( .....Q@.
0000-0cc0:  14 00 51 40-05 14 00 51-40 05 14 00-02 41 c8 e0  ..Q@...Q @....A..
0000-0cd0:  d1 40 05 14-00 52 8f ad-30 12 97 9e-87 23 06 80  .@...R.. 0....#..
0000-0cd6:  0c 7a 73 49-48 0f                                .zsIH.

Hex dump of file 2:
file name: 1_Video.dcm
mime type: 

0000-0010:  cc 4b 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00  .K...... ........
0000-0020:  00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0030:  00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0040:  00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0050:  00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0060:  00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0070:  00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0080:  00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0090:  44 49 43 4d-08 00 18 00-55 49 34 00-31 35 46 44  DICM.... UI4.15FD
0000-00a0:  41 36 34 2d-37 37 34 36-2d 34 36 43-46 2d 39 38  A64-7746 -46CF-98
0000-00b0:  44 42 2d 30-30 33 43 45-30 35 31 42-39 46 33 2e  DB-003CE 051B9F3.
0000-00c0:  35 31 33 31-2e 31 36 37-35 34 2e 36-31 39 35 36  5131.167 54.61956
0000-00d0:  08 00 20 00-44 41 08 00-32 30 30 37-30 39 31 38  ....DA.. 20070918
0000-00e0:  08 00 21 00-44 41 08 00-32 30 30 37-30 39 31 38  ..!.DA.. 20070918
0000-00f0:  08 00 31 00-54 4d 06 00-31 36 33 36-34 30 08 00  ..1.TM.. 163640..
0000-0100:  32 00 54 4d-06 00 31 36-33 36 34 31-08 00 60 00  2.TM..16 3641..`.
0000-0110:  43 53 04 00-4f 43 54 20-08 00 70 00-4c 4f 12 00  CS..OCT. ..p.LO..
0000-0120:  43 61 72 6c-20 5a 65 69-73 73 20 4d-65 64 69 74  Carl.Zei ss.Medit
0000-0130:  65 63 08 00-10 10 53 48-04 00 4f 43-54 33 08 00  ec....SH ..OCT3..
0000-0140:  90 10 4c 4f-04 00 33 30-30 30 10 00-10 00 50 4e  ..LO..30 00....PN
0000-0150:  06 00 63 33-5e 32 30 34-10 00 20 00-4c 4f 08 00  ..c3^204 ....LO..
0000-0160:  31 33 36 35-33 37 37 20-10 00 30 00-44 41 08 00  1365377. ..0.DA..
0000-0170:  31 39 34 35-30 31 31 32-10 00 40 00-43 53 02 00  19450112 ..@.CS..
0000-0180:  4d 20 10 00-54 21 53 48-02 00 5c 20-10 00 60 21  M...T!SH ..\...`!
0000-0190:  53 48 06 00-57 68 69 74-65 20 10 00-00 40 4c 54  SH..Whit e....@LT
0000-01a0:  00 00 18 00-00 10 4c 4f-0a 00 33 30-30 30 2d 36  ......LO ..3000-6
0000-01b0:  37 30 37 20-18 00 20 10-4c 4f 0c 00-34 2e 30 2e  707..... LO..4.0.
0000-01c0:  37 20 28 30-31 33 32 29-20 00 0d 00-55 49 28 00  7.(0132) ....UI(.
0000-01d0:  31 35 46 44-41 36 34 2d-37 37 34 36-2d 34 36 43  15FDA64- 7746-46C
0000-01e0:  46 2d 39 38-44 42 2d 30-30 33 43 45-30 35 31 42  F-98DB-0 03CE051B
0000-01f0:  39 46 33 2e-35 31 33 31-20 00 0e 00-55 49 2e 00  9F3.5131 ....UI..
```

Comment: Can you make the files available for checking?

Comment: Your question is lacking a [mcve]. In that case, we need the data in the question itself, for example as a hexdump. Note that it needs to be **Minimal** which may be hard to achieve (please don't post kilobytes of data). Good luck!

Comment: The data are in the links

Comment: **In the question itself**, not as an external link. If the link changes or dies your question loses meaning. Please check the following help: [mcve].

Comment: They are binary files, I don't quite understand how I can insert them in the question itself. I've read the link as I'm a longtime user.

Comment: @gelazari You are being suggested to provide the data as a [hex dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump). I would recommend posting only the first few hundred bytes if you're willing to go this way.

Comment: @E_net4 Yes I knew that but the hex dumps are humongous and cannot be submitted in their whole (as you pointed out). Anyway

Comment: Looking at the hex dump, the JFIF content starts at offset 0184 (hex) with `ff d8 ff e0` and then the string JFIF - if you can delete the preceding bytes from 0000-0183 and save to jpeg extension it might open in an image viewer (excess data at the end won't matter).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have stumbled upon a file containing several non-conformities to the DICOM standard. The one that's most critical is the lack of a file meta header, which would include the file's transfer syntax. It also includes primitive identifier values (such as `15FDA64-7746-46CF-98DB-003CE051B9F3.5131.16754.61956`), which are not valid UIDs (due to the presence of hyphens), along with some other inconsistencies. This makes it inevitable harder to manipulate using open, standard-conforming tools and libraries. Once a transfer syntax is unknown, external assumptions need to be made one way or another.

But all is not lost in this particular case. The `dcmdump` tool, by detecting `ExplicitVRLittleEndian` as the transfer syntax, has managed to recover some attributes (some parts removed for brevity):

```
# Dicom-File-Format

# Dicom-Meta-Information-Header
# Used TransferSyntax: Unknown Transfer Syntax

# Dicom-Data-Set
# Used TransferSyntax: Little Endian Explicit
(0008,0018) UI [15FDA64-7746-46CF-98DB-003CE051B9F3.5131.16754.61956] #  52, 1 SOPInstanceUID

[...]

(0008,0060) CS [OCT]                                    #   4, 1 Modality

[...]

(0028,0002) US 1                                        #   2, 1 SamplesPerPixel
(0028,0004) CS [MONOCHROME2]                            #  12, 1 PhotometricInterpretation
(0028,0010) US 240                                      #   2, 1 Rows
(0028,0011) US 320                                      #   2, 1 Columns
(0028,0034) IS [1\1]                                    #   4, 2 PixelAspectRatio
(0028,0100) US 8                                        #   2, 1 BitsAllocated
(0028,0101) US 8                                        #   2, 1 BitsStored
(0028,0102) US 7                                        #   2, 1 HighBit
(0028,0103) US 0                                        #   2, 1 PixelRepresentation

[...]

(7fe0,0010) OW 0000\0c00\506a\2020\0a0d\0a87\0000\1800\7466\7079\706a\2078\0000... # 19404, 1 PixelData
```

The necessary details to retrieve the pixel data appear to be present at first glance. However, the `PixelData` has a length of 19404 bytes, whereas a raw 320x240x1 bitmap would require 76800 bytes. This is where `pydicom` ultimately fails, as it attempts to read the pixel data as an uncompressed array of pixels. At this point we can assume that the image data is in some other encoding. Writing the DICOM element value to a separate file:

```
with open('PixelData.bin', mode='wb') as f:
    f.write(myfile.PixelData)
```

We can do a magic test with `file`:

```
$ file PixelData.bin
PixelData.bin: JPEG 2000 Part 2 (JPX)
```

The `PixelData` field contains a JPEG 2000 image file. The PIL image module can handle the format, so we can manually transform the data into an array without the assistance of `pydicom`. According to [Open PIL image from byte file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908639/open-pil-image-from-byte-file):

```
from PIL import Image
import io

image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(myfile.PixelData))
pixels = np.array(image.getdata()).reshape((myfile.Columns, myfile.Rows))
```

To summarise:

- Non-conforming DICOM files can be problematic to use because they won't work well with existing tools;
- With a set of assumptions about the transfer syntax (namely assuming the most common form that is VR-explicit little endian), there's a chance of obtaining the necessary pieces to recover the pixel data.
- If the pixel data DICOM element is fully identified, it may still be in an unspecified encoding. Luckily, image loading tools such as the one in PIL can automatically detect the underlying format in some cases.

Comment: Thank you @E_net4. Exactly what I was looking for. Feel free to start a conversation with me in order to ask you a couple of extra things.

Comment: I checked the DICOM file: the File Meta Information (meta header) is missing, which is mandatory for a DICOM file and which contains the Transfer Syntax UID of the DICOM dataset. By default, dcmdump tries to guess the Transfer Syntax (if missing). This can be avoided by using option --read-file-only (+fo). What you wrote about the invalid UID value is true for the SOP Instance UID, the Series Instance UID and the Study Instance UID, but not for the Transfer Syntax UID (because it is missing, see above). I hope the DICOM file has not been created by the mentioned Manufacturer (see dump output).

Comment: By the way, there are further issues with this DICOM file, e.g. the Private Date Elements are not encoded correctly (the Private Creator Element is missing), Pixel Aspect Ratio should not be present in case of square pixels, maximum length of DS (Decimal String) values exceeded...

Comment: @J.Riesmeier Good points, I will mend the answer where deemed necessary. It's true that there are other issues in the file, but I chose to address the main concern of recovering the pixel data into an array.

Comment: @J.Riesmeier Why do you hope that the DICOM file has not been created by the mentioned manufacturer?

Comment: @gelazari Unless the file has been deliberately modified by a third party before it reached your hands, it exposes a manufacturer of machines producing malformed DICOM, which is worrying to say the least.

Comment: Should I worry about the contents of my post then?

Comment: @gelazari As E_net4 already wrote: since the DICOM file shows numerous violations of the DICOM standard and other inconsistencies, I hope it was not produced by a "real" machine (i.e. an official software release by the vendor). But if so, you should inform the vendor about this.