# distortion after opening an image from bytes with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908639/open-pil-image-from-byte-file) post and tried to open an image from bytes and actually i made it. but the problem is the image is not showing correctly. i don't know what is the original format of image but i know this is an dental X-Ray image. i`m asking if someone knows where is the problem and how can i fix it.

[image]

```py
from PIL import Image
import io

image_data = ... #bytes
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
image.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I saved the above image in my pc and then opened it with the python with your code and its opening perfectly.

```
from PIL import Image
import io

image_data = open('CdRVp.jpg', 'rb+').read()
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
image.show()
```