# UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file PNG BytesIO

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm getting this error trying to read a png image pulled from a webpage with requests...

```
    UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fa8aca13ef0>

Traceback:
File "/home/user/.conda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 333, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/home/user/app/app.py", line 463, in <module>
    img_details, message, title, invalid_file_paths, dates_df = pull_imgs(url=url, user=user, password=password, input_dir=input_dir)
File "/home/user/app/app.py", line 229, in pull_imgs
    img = Image.open(img_bytes)
File "/home/user/.conda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3023, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(
```

Here is the segment of code that is causing the error:

```
for photo in valid_file_paths:

    # PULL PHOTO
    response = requests.get(photo[0], auth=(user, password), stream=True)
    
    # FILENAME
    file = extract_file(photo[0])[1]
    ext = photo[1]
    filename = file + '.' + ext
    
    img_bytes = io.BytesIO(response.content)                
    img = Image.open(img_bytes)
    img.save(os.path.join(input_dir, filename), format=ext, optimize=True)
```

I have tried to resolve the issue using solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077366/pil-cannot-identify-image-file-for-io-bytesio-object), but was unsuccessful. Any advice is appreciated. Simply using a try statement to avoid the problem files doesn't work for me. I need a way to read them even if they are corrupted, truncated or some other issue.

Comment: Please click [edit] and show the first 20-30 bytes of `response.content`.

Comment: according to this, if image is fine , should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908639/open-pil-image-from-byte-file

Comment: does  img = Image.open(response.content) works ??

Comment: Image.open(response.content) fails

Comment: Please see my first comment `print(response.content[:20])`

Comment: Thank you for recommending that I print the response.content! I found out the the url I was scrapping was changed from http to https and my code was no longer pulling images but, instead, html headers.

Answer (score 2):

print(response.content[:20]) showed that I was pulling some bits of HTML, rather than the actual image. Don't be like me and always check the output of your requests.

Comment: Well done! Always worth checking.