# Pyhon change byte image format

Tags: python, image, webp

I have a byte type image and I need to change its format from jpg or png to webp using Python without saving.

And the result should also be of byte type. No intermediate saving to disk.

How can i do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: WHat does this mean? Extensions are in filenames, not data. Do you mean you want to convert the image encoding format from JPEG to WEBP?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908639/open-pil-image-from-byte-file) to read image data to PIL from a `bytes` object, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646286/how-to-write-png-image-to-string-with-the-pil) to re-encode it and write the results to a `bytes` object.

Comment: What's a *"byte type image"* please? Please click [edit] and make a proper [mcve] that shows what you really have and what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Note that changing the **extension** of a file is nearly pointless without changing the **content**. I think it is a common idea amongst Windows users, but do you think that changing the extension of an Excel spreadsheet from `.xls` to `.mp3` will suddenly make it an audio file?