# Ctk images in sqlite3 database

Tags: python, customtkinter

I am small programer and devoloping a program with python
i used sqlite and PIL to convert my image into rb mode and saved it in binary code. I fetched the image later in the program and i wanted to convert the image to a CTkImage. a error shows up as follow

CTkImage: dark_image must be instance if PIL.Image.Image, not <class 'bytes'>

unfortunately i can't share the code because its really big about 791 lines. Can anyone help me?

i tried many things and it didn't eork

Comment: you need to convert bytes to an image first like in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32908899/13629335)

Comment: I don't really understand that answer

Comment: i am just a 13y old programer in python and I don't know much deeper in it.

Comment: can you please suggest some other answer or can you answer?

Comment: You should provide a [mre] if you expect anyone to answer your question.

Comment: Post traceback error.

Comment: @Thingamabobs i tried your previous response abd it worked.